# Simple program crash

Tags: c++, fsm

I tried to implement a very simple FSM in C++. Problem is, that this program will crash immediately, after executing. I am new to C++ so I can't find any bug here. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class State {
    public:
        virtual ~State() {}
        virtual void update();
};

class Hey_state : public State {
    public:
        virtual void update() { cout << "Hey!\n";}
};

class How_state : public State {
    public:
        virtual void update() { cout << "How are you?\n";}
};

class Stranger {
    public:
        Stranger(State *startState)
        : currState(startState) {}
        void greet() {
            currState->update();
        }
        void setState(State *s) {currState = s;}
    private:
        State *currState;
};

int main() {
    Hey_state *h;
    Stranger s(h);
    s.greet();
}
```

Comment: Can you use your debugger and tell us what line it crashes on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hey_state *h;`

This creates a pointer to a `Hey_state` which could point anywhere randomly in memory. No object is actually created.

```
Stranger s(h);
s.greet();
```

This attempts to use the Hey_state that was never created, giving an error.

Try:

```
Hey_state h;
Stranger s(&h);
s.greet();
```

That creates an object of `Hey_state`, and passes a pointer to that object to `Stranger s`

Answer (score 5):

`Hey_state *h` is a pointer.

Where does it point?  **You don't know.**

Its value is *uninitialized*.

Later, you *dereference* the same pointer, now copied to `currState`.

```
        currState->update();
```

What is there?  **You don't know.**

You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: *Since you are new to C++, it should be mentioned that you must learn to use a debugger.  Then problems like this will stop being so mysterious.